# Quick equivalence class clarification question

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

A quick clarification question, what is an equivalence class of a function? For example if you have an identity function on all integers $I_{Z}$, what would $[I_{Z}]$ = ? I know that when you have a relation, the equivalence class of an element is composed of all the values its related to, but how does that look like when you have a function?

The actual question asks for a function that is not equal to that identity function but fulfills some conditions one of which is that it is part of its equivalence class, but that really confuses me, so the class is composed of functions?

EDIT: This is the question (sorry I didn't want to ask for help with my homework... it's just the concept I can't grasp):
Let $I_{Z}$ be the identity function on $\Bbb{Z}$ (so $I_{Z}(x) = x$ for all $x \in Z$). Find a function $f \neq I_{Z}$ which belongs to the equivalence class $[I_{Z}]$.

Comment: Every function induces an equivalence relation: $xRy\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$. Perhaps what is meant is the equivalence class of the relation induced by the function.

Comment: Seeing the original text of the question would help a lot in answering this.

Comment: Yes, this is ill-formed. An equivalence class is defined by an equivalence relation, so the equivalence class of $I_Z$ can only be determined if we know the equivalence relation (and the set on which the relationship is defined.)

Comment: Ok I added the full question, sorry I just didn't want to make it look like I'm asking for solutions to my homework so I tried my best to describe it

Comment: @Shahab I figured something like that, but that would mean that each element would only be related to itself, so $[I_{Z}] = I_{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the same equivalence relation as in [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357776/12042), yes, $[f]$ is a set of functions: it’s the set of all functions $g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ such that $g-f$ is a constant function. Note that $I_{\Bbb Z}(n)=n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$. Thus, $[I_{\Bbb Z}]$ is the set of all functions $g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ such that $g(n)-n$ is a constant that does not depend on $n$. Can you think of a function $f$ such that $f(n)-n$ is always $2$, say? Or $7$? Or any other fixed integer?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be $f(n) = 2 - n$? So a general solution would be $f(n) = k - n$ where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $k \neq 0$? Still can't understand how the class fits into it, like can you explain what the class of a function would look like? Any simple one will do.

Comment: @crazymao: Almost, but your algebra went a bit astray: that’s $f(n)=n+2$. The functions in the equivalence class $[I_{\Bbb Z}$ are precisely the functions $f_k$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$, where $f_k(n)=n+k$. If $s(n)=n^2$ is the squaring function, $[s]$ contains precisely the functions $f(n)=n^2+k$, one for each $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ohhh I see, wow that was a bad mistake :P thanks so much for clearing that up!

Comment: @crazymao: You’re welcome!

Comment: +1 for finding the actual question. (The OP should have included all the necessary details.)